# Why does output of faker::lorem produce dashes at the beginning of the string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, faker, lorem-ipsum

Using faker gem with rails to generate some fake data. When I use faker::lorem the output includes dashes in front of the string.

```
namespace :db do
  desc "Fill database with sample data"
  task populate: :environment do
    7.times do |l|
      line = Line.create!(sentence: Faker::Lorem.sentences(2))
    end
  end
end
```

Like:

```
---
- Odit consectetur perspiciatis delectus sunt quo est.
- Tempore excepturi soluta aliquam perferendis.
```

Any idea why this function returns the Lorem with dashes? Easiest way to strip them out?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Lorem.sentences returns an array. When I added .join(" ") on the end, the dashes were gone and it read correctly. The dashes must be what happens when you try to put an array into a string.

Comment: It's actually the gem generating YAML when converted to a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kevin and Deefour mention in the comments, Faker::Lorem returns an array.

Since we're asking Ruby to store it in a string, Ruby interprets it per the guidelines for [YAML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML), which is a way of representing data structures in text.

If you're encountering this issue, the simplest fix is to use Ruby's built in array-to-string conversion method `.join(x)`, which takes string x as the delimiter to add.